# C++0x perfect forwarding getting in the way of copy ctor?

Tags: c++11

Using MSVC2010...

I have a struct that wraps a std::string, with standard move ctor's defined, as well as a perfect forwarding ctor to forward an argument to the std::string ctor.

```
struct Wrapper
{
  std::string value;

  Wrapper()
  {
  }

  Wrapper( Wrapper const& rhs )
    :value(rhs.value)
  {
  }

  Wrapper( Wrapper&& rhs )
    :value(std::move(rhs.value))
  {
  }

  Wrapper& operator=( Wrapper const& rhs )
  {
    value = rhs.value;
    return *this;
  }

  Wrapper& operator=( Wrapper&& rhs )
  {
    value = std::move(rhs.value);
    return *this;
  }


  template<typename StringT>
  Wrapper( StringT&& value )
    :value(std::forward<StringT>(value))
  {
  }
};
```

However now it seems I cannot copy-construct a Wrapper from another wrapper

```
Wrapper w0;
Wrapper w1(w0);
```

This results in a compile error pointing at the perfect forwarding ctor, saying it cannot convert a Wrapper to a std::string. Is this correct behavior? Shouldn't the compiler call the copy ctor, versus the templated overload?

```
1>t:\depot\warp\code\apps\pf_test\main.cpp(56): error C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Wrapper' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'Wrapper' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          t:\depot\warp\code\apps\pf_test\main.cpp(63) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Wrapper::Wrapper<Wrapper&>(StringT)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              StringT=Wrapper &
1>          ]
1>
```

If I define another copy ctor, one that takes a non-const reference to Wrapper (shown below), then everything seems fine... Is this the way moving forward? Or did I mess something up? Or is this a bug in VS2010?

```
  Wrapper( Wrapper& rhs )
    :value(rhs.value)
  {
  }
```

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need to hand write all of those constructors.  They've added the ability to use 'Wrapper() = default;' syntax.  It'll give you the default constructors and assignment operators (you'll need to do that for each ctr/op you want).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - it seems VC2010 doesn't support this yet

Comment: Sorry, I forget sometimes since I primarily use gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct behaviour.

There are two constructors that might be called in this case - your copy constructor and the template one. However, template constructor might deduce the type to be **perfect match** (`Wrapper(StringT&&)` with `StringT = Wrapper&` yields perfect match `Wrapper(Wrapper&)`) and thus gets used instead of copy constructor.

Suggested workaround - use `std::enable_if` from `<type_traits>`:

```
template <typename StringT>
Wrapper(StringT&& value,
  typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_same<
      StringT,
      Wrapper&
    >::value
  >::type* = 0)
  : value(std::forward<StringT>(value))
{ }
```

See it working [here](http://ideone.com/CDjyR).

Comment: Interesting...

So the template overload is picked before the compiler even considers that the lvalue I picked can't be bound to the rvalue reference StringT&& ?  I'm not sure if I buy that, since the error message is at the point of the string ctor, it seems it's already decided that the argument types are compatible? Or do I just have a misunderstanding of the order this all gets resolved in

Comment: The lvalue **can** be bound the StringT&&. Due to reference collapsing rules, `StringT&&` with `StringT = Wrapper&` (which is `Wrapper& &&`) collapses into `Wrapper&`.

Comment: @MikeNicolella The template constructor eats the non-const reference (Wrapper&) that you are trying to construct it with. That is why when you add Wrapper(Wrapper& w) it should work. If you were testing this with a class that took more than one input (2 or more values instead of the one value), you wouldn't have noticed this issue.

Comment: Aha, I missed that T&& can actually bind to lvalues. Hmph. Thanks!

Comment: And thanks for the workaround. Not surprised at the verbosity :)

Comment: @MikeNicolella: T&& can't bind to lvalues. The trick here is in the details of T- in perfect forwarding to an lvalue, it becomes (const) T&, where T is the underlying value type, e.g. int. Thus, the *actual* reference type ends up being (possibly const) T&, as a ((const)T&)&& decays to a (const) T&.

Comment: @DeadMG: Assuming that `T` is not concrete type, I suppose you _can_ say that lvalue of type `U` can be bound to `T&&` via `U& &&`. Of course, this cannot be said if `T` is concrete type.